# jQuery extend $.fn and calling method syntax

Tags: jquery

I understand that you call a method like this when you are extending `$.fn`.

( `$ == jQuery` )

```
//$("div").myMethod();

$.fn.extend({
   myMethod: function(){...}
});
```

And like this when you extend the jQuery Object:

```
//$.myMethod2();

$.extend({
    myMethod2: function(){...}
});
```

But I don't quite understand what the `$()` is doing here:

// There are a few methods being called here. Some with the same method name (initiate) which is bad.

// But maybe that is why the blank jQuery object is needed so the method names don't clash

```
$(function() {

    $().functionName({
      something: 'something'
    }).myMethod();

    $().func1({
      x: 1
    }).initiate();

    $().func2({
      y: 2
    }).initiate();

});
```

Does it have to do with the fact the method is being called including the function name?

Thanks in advance and hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

`$()` creates an empty jQuery object (wrappet set). I wouldn't know why someone would do something like this. Basically, you're calling `functionName` and `myMethod` on an empty set of elements = nothing should happen.

```
jQuery().css({
   'foo': 'bar'
}).show();
```

Comment: I don't know why someone would do it either, but given that it's a question about user defined functions, we can't know that nothing will happen. `$.fn.extend({ test: function() { alert('this will happen'); } }); $().test();`

Comment: @David: you're right. Of course the code from those methods would execute. But there would be no reason to have such methods in the jQuery `.fn` namespace since they can't act on wrapped elements.

Comment: I entirely agree. OP has most likely encountered code written by somebody who didn't know what they were doing, but I would be surprised if the code at hand didn't *do* anything.

Comment: This is indeed the case - i have encountered code written by somebody else :\
I have edited my question with a bit more info. Could the $() be necessary because of duplicate method names?

Answer (score 1):

Before jQuery 1.4 calling `jQuery()` would have been the same as `jQuery(document)`. Since then it's been changed to return an empty set instead. So since jQuery 1.4, `jQuery()` is the equivalent of `jQuery([])`. Even so, the latter was and is the recommended way of getting an empty set just to make sure not to confuse anyone.

Anyways, my guess is that the code you're asking about is old, and uses a deprecated way to access the `document` node, not to mention that it is/was a bad practice to do so even back then. `$()` is probably supposed to be `$` or `$(document)`.

But, that's not to say that an empty jQuery set is wrong or useless. Adam Kiss have written a [post on his blog](http://adam.kissyour.net/11-using-empty-set-with-jquery-part-1) about the usefulness of empty sets.

And finally, some other ways to extend jQuery:

```
(function($){
    $.myMethod = function() {
    };

    $.fn.myMethod = function() {
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thanks very much all for your responses.
I guess 'old dodgy code' is good in a way, as it makes you dig a little deeper into how things actually work :)